# Why does this redirect apply?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a simple `Redirect` in my htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /foobar /johndoe/foobar
```

unfortunately, this url:

`/foobar/barfoo` also gets redirected - why? In my understanding, only `/foobar` should be redirected when using the `Redirect` command, shouldnt it?

I feel that this is more comfy than writing `RewriteRule`s

Comment: The documentation seems to confirm that it should behave the way you expect: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect All the examples use quotes, perhaps worth trying out (`Redirect 301 "/foobar" ...`)

Comment: @Pekka웃 really? I feel this pours salt into my soup: `Then any request beginning with URL-Path will return a redirect request`

Comment: well, using `RedirectMatch` also works :)

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the solution. `/foobar$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, `Redirect` seems to just check if the URL to check is in the beginning of the current path (at least my tests say that, the documentation is not 100% clear about it).

But, to avoid using `RewriteRule` (since it might be overkill), simple `RedirectMatch` also works:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "^/foobar$" "/johndoe/foobar"
```

I would still be thankful for additional advice, whether this isnt possible to solve without "regex" and/or `RewriteRule`